# jQuery: find-click

Tags: jquery

I have a `ul`

```
    <div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://apple.com">first</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apple.com">second</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/iphone/">third</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">third1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">third2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">third3</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">third4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li><!--fi altres -->
    <li><a href="http://apple.com">forth</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.apple.com/iphone/">fith</a>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">fith1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">fith2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://apple.com">fifh3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li><!--fi nosaltres -->
  </ul>
</div><!--menu -->
```

I have a jQuery that works fine in hover:

```
$(function(){
    $('#menu ul li').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('ul').fadeIn()
        },function() {
            $(this).find('ul').fadeOut()
        }
    )
})
```

The same doesn't work with click:

```
$(function(){
    $("#menu ul li").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('ul').fadeIn()
    });
})
```

When I click to fadeIn one submenu I have to fadeIn before the others submenus. How?

Comment: You've quoted the same code twice, under *"I have a jQuery that works fine in hover:"* and (with different indentation) under *"The same don't works with click:"*.

Comment: It works here http://jsfiddle.net/cpn6h/1/

Comment: this is not complete and you quoted the same code twice "both are click events" please check your question again

Comment: please note that mootools is the selected library in your jsfiddle, NOT jquery

Comment: It works great when you select jQuery as the Library in jsFiddle.

Comment: It's a really odd approach, makes no logical sense... you use `preventDefault()` on an `li` which really doesn't have any default click/hover behavior to prevent, but you still have a good, clickable anchor link inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my guess is that you want something like this.

```
$("#menu ul li").hover(function(event) {
        $(this).find("ul").fadeIn("slow");
    },
    function(event) {
        $(this).find("ul").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

**EDIT** I think I got it:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#menu > ul > li").click(function(event) {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ( $this.find("ul").length && event.target.href/*.split('/').pop()*/ == $('> a', this).attr('href') ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $this.siblings().find("ul").fadeOut("slow");
            $this.find("ul").fadeIn("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

"`&& event.target.href.split('/').pop() == $('> a', this).attr('href')`" is to avoid disabling default functionnality (open the link) in the submenu.

**NOTA BENE** if the sublink is exactly the same as the memu link, the sublink wont' work. You can replace "http:://aaa.com/" by "http://www.aaa.com/" in the menu *OR* submenu  (but not both)

Comment: Sorry, I did not explain well. I have no problems with the hover. The question is: how to CLICK and get the submenu

Comment: i think I understand what you want. check my edited answer and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpn6h/12/). when you click a menu with submenu, it hides other submenus if they are displayed, and display the submenu. If a menu WITHOUT a submenu is clicked, it opens the link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your fiddle works fine. I understand and I think it is great the way you hide the others submenus. But I have problems with the menus without a submenu and their links: 1-It works in the fiddle but when I copy-paste in a file it doesn't: http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves2/2-forum.html I have done so many times and I don't find the problem.

Comment: well as your script is in the page head, it tries to bind the click event to a non existing element, as #menu is created later in the page body. Try to add `$(document).ready(function() { *_CODE_HERE_* });` around the code. edit: oh well, added it in my response ;)

Comment: You're right. Sorry, my mistake was stupid. As you can see, I'm just learning. Now it works fine in computers, iPad but it doesn't work in iPhone. Why?

Comment: After trying so many things I find out that if I don't link to the google api and I download the "jquery-1.7.min.js" everything works in the iPhone/iPad. I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: I don't understand : .length I suppose it targets the items in the menu that have submenus, but how?  you don't specify what length

Comment: I can't answer you about specific iphone stuff. About $().length: it's the "standard" way of checking if an element exist. If jquery find one or more elements, length will be > 0, else it won't exist. In short, it's saying "if the clicked li contains another ul", do something (here: display submenu). Now here comes the trick: if you click a submenu item, the "this" is still the main menu, and the right part of the "&&" is to check if it's a submenu or a top menu item which has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify that you wanted to use jQuery. Since $ wasn't hooked up with jQuery, it returned null. Under Choose Framework select a version of jQuery for onLoad, and your code works.

You might want to look into what roselan proposed for an improvement to functionality however.